# CORS issue in Setting Background Image

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fabricjs

I am setting an image as a background image using the following code:

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = "<%=@templates[0][1]%>";
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.onload = function(){
       canvas.setBackgroundImage(img.src, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        left: 0,
        top: 0
       });
    };
```

When I save the canvas I am using the following code:

var img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
var blobBin = atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]);
var array = [];
for(var i = 0; i < blobBin.length; i++) {
  array.push(blobBin.charCodeAt(i));
}
```

I am getting the following error when I am saving:

```
Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported.
```

I have googled it but unable to understand how to solve it. So please tell me the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The crossorigin attribute is a CORS settings attribute. Its purpose is to allow images, fonts etc from third-party sites that allow cross-origin access to be used with canvas. So the CORS header should be set to allow to pull images.Or another option would be to load the image convert it to base64 and then save it on your server and then add it on the canvas

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should put `img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";` before setting the source (`img.src = "<%=@templates[0][1]%>";`).

That should fix it.